# Can't access a function that is declared later

Tags: javascript, function, scope

EDITED SOLVED: the problem was that inNum called action(ac) => (ac as a reference) where in order to call the desired case the argument should have been 'ac' =>(a string). Thank @floor!

In an assignment I built a calculator, and one function is using another function which is declared below it to clear the entries

```
function inNum(num) {
  if(arrHistory.indexOf('=') != -1) {
    action(ac);
  }

  (entry.length === 1 && entry[0] === 0) ? entry[0] = num: typeof entry[0] == 'string' ? entry = [num] : entry.push(num);

  return $('#entry')[0].textContent = entry.join('');
}

function action(action) {
  switch(action) {
    case 'ac':
      arrHistory = [];
      entry = [0];
      return $('#history')[0].textContent = arrHistory.join(''), 
            $('#entry')[0].textContent = entry.join('');
```

It seems that inNum can't access action. why is it? Aren't both of the functions (inNum and action) on the global scope and thus accessible to each other in runtime?

I tried to solve this problem by writing the functions as methods in an object which contains all of my code, but inNum still couldn't call action with the argument AC.
I know that the simple solution is to write the case for switch(ac) instead of calling the function, but I'm interested in understanding the rules behind this behavior.

```js
var entry = [0];
var arrHistory = [];

function inNum(num) {
 if(arrHistory.indexOf('=') != -1) {
  action(ac);
 }
 (entry.length === 1 && entry[0] === 0) ? entry[0] = num: typeof entry[0] == 'string' ? entry = [num] : entry.push(num);
 return $('#entry')[0].textContent = entry.join('');
}

function action(action) {
 switch(action) {
  case 'ac':
   arrHistory = [];
   entry = [0];
   return $('#history')[0].textContent = arrHistory.join(''), $('#entry')[0].textContent = entry.join('');
  case 'ce':
   if(typeof arrHistory[arrHistory.length - 1] == 'string') {
    //if (typeof Number(arrHistory[arrHistory.length - 1]) != 'number')
    arrHistory.pop();
    entry = [0];
    $('#entry')[0].textContent = entry.join('');
   }
   else {
    arrHistory = [];
    entry = [0];
    return $('#history')[0].textContent = arrHistory.join(''),
     $('#entry')[0].textContent = entry.join('');
   }
   return $('#history')[0].textContent = arrHistory.join('');
  case 'divide':
   if(typeof entry[0] === 'number' && typeof entry[entry.length - 1] === 'number') {
    arrHistory.push(Number(entry.join('')));
    arrHistory.push('\/');
    entry = [String.fromCharCode(247)];
    $('#entry')[0].textContent = entry.join('');
    return $('#history')[0].textContent = arrHistory.join('');
   }
   break;
  case 'multiply':
   if(typeof entry[0] === 'number' && typeof entry[entry.length - 1] === 'number') {
    arrHistory.push(Number(entry.join('')));
    arrHistory.push('\*');
    entry = ['X'];
    $('#entry')[0].textContent = entry.join('');
    return $('#history')[0].textContent = arrHistory.join('');
   }
   break;
  case 'add':
   if(typeof entry[0] === 'number' && typeof entry[entry.length - 1] === 'number') {
    arrHistory.push(Number(entry.join('')));
    arrHistory.push('\+');
    entry = ['\+'];
    $('#entry')[0].textContent = entry.join('');
    return $('#history')[0].textContent = arrHistory.join('');
   }
   break;
  case 'subtract':
   if(typeof entry[0] === 'number' && typeof entry[entry.length - 1] === 'number') {
    arrHistory.push(Number(entry.join('')));
    arrHistory.push('\-');
    entry = ['\-'];
    $('#entry')[0].textContent = entry.join('');
    return $('#history')[0].textContent = arrHistory.join('');
   }
   break;
  case 'calculate':
   // MULTIPLICATION AND DIVISION METHOD
   function mulDiv(acumulator, element, index, arr) {
    if(arr[index + 1] == '*' || arr[index + 1] == '/') {
     if(index < arr.length - 2) {
      let mulDivSum;
      switch(arr[index + 1]) {
       case '*':
        mulDivSum = element * arr[index + 2]
        arr.splice(index, 2);
        break;
       case '/':
        mulDivSum = element / arr[index + 2]
        arr.splice(index, 2);
        break;
      }
      acumulator.push(mulDivSum);
      return acumulator;
     }
    }
    else {
     acumulator.push(element);
     return acumulator
    }
   }
   // ADDITION AND SUBTRACTION METHOD
   function addSub(sum, element, index, arr) {
    switch(element) {
     case "+":
      if(index < arr.length - 1) {
       sum += arr[index + 1];
       break;
      }
     case "-":
      if(index < arr.length - 1) {
       sum -= arr[index + 1];
       break;
      }
    }
    return sum;
   }
   if((entry.length === 1 && typeof entry[0] == 'number') || (entry[entry.length - 1] == 'number')) {
    arrHistory.push(Number(entry.join('')));
    let result = arrHistory.reduce(mulDiv, [])
     .reduce(addSub, arrHistory[0]);
    arrHistory.push('=');
    arrHistory.push(result)
    $('#history')[0].textContent = arrHistory.join('');
    $('#entry')[0].textContent = Number(result);
   }
   break;
  case 'decimal':
   if(entry.indexOf('.') === -1) {
    entry.push('\.');
    $('#entry')[0].textContent = entry.join('');
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: When asking for help, please indent and format your code in a reasonable, consistent way. (It's a good idea when *not* asking for help, too.) Also be sure to quote (verbatim) the error you're getting, right now you effectively are saying it "doesn't work" but not telling us what happens.

Comment: crazy use of ternary, btw.

Comment: That ternary is completely out of control.

Comment: ZZZzzz what a ternary condition!!

Comment: From what's in your question, `inNum` absolutely does have access to `action`. I'd check for conflicts on the identifier `action` (since you say these are globals, and the global namespace is **very** crowded -- one of the many reasons not to use globals [consider introducing a scoping function around your code so things are global to *your* code, but not actually globals]).

Comment: shouldn't ac be a string? you are passing it as a variable but i dont see it declared. you should check the console for errors.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @floor: Good point, I assume you mean in `action(ac);` in `inNum`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder correct

Comment: The snippet you just added to the question never actually does anything. It defines functions but doesn't call any of them!

Comment: @floor That solved it! thanks! how can I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: @AlonParag no need just make sure to check the console for errors next time.

Comment: Nice one @floor :-)